# Existence of certain factorization of simplicial map

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, proof-explanation, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

The following is an image of a proof from Hovey's *Model Categories*:

[image: proof]

---

> How exactly do we know that $s\restriction_{\partial{\Delta[n]}}$
>   factors through $X_n$?

Since $\partial{\Delta[n]}$ has only finitely many non-degenerate simplices, it is $\lambda$-small for any limit cardinal $\lambda$, but I'm not sure how this (at least directly) implies the factorization we want.

Comment: Because the map $X_n \rightarrow L$ is an isomorphism (bijection) on $(n-1)$-simplices and smaller. So the map $s: \partial \Delta^n \rightarrow L$ must lift to $X_n \rightarrow L$ since $\partial \Delta^n$ only consists of $(n-1)-$simplices and smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more rigorous way to state what I said in my comment is to utilize the $(n-1)-$skeleton functor $sk_{n-1}$.

We know that $sk_{n-1} X_n \rightarrow sk_{n-1} L$ is an isomorphism of simplicial sets. We also know that $sk_{n-1} \partial \Delta^n = \partial \Delta^n$.

So any map $s : \partial \Delta^n \rightarrow L$ gives a map $sk_{n-1} s : \partial \Delta^n \rightarrow sk_{n-1} L$ which then gives a map $s': \partial \Delta^n \rightarrow sk_{n-1} X_n$ because $sk_{n-1} L$ and $sk_{n-1} X$ are isomorphic. There is a natural inclusion $i:sk_{n-1} X_n \rightarrow X_n$ which gives you the desired lift $i \circ s': \partial \Delta^n \rightarrow X_n $. Uniqueness of the lift comes from injectivity of $X_n \rightarrow L$ on $(n-1)-$simplices and below.

Comment: It seems that this argument works by using the truncation functor instead of its left adjoint, the skeleton functor.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 ah well $sk_n$ can mean both a functor $sSet \rightarrow sSet$ and $Set^{\Delta_{\leq n}^{op}} \rightarrow sSet$. I thought it was obvious that I meant $sSet \rightarrow sSet$ from context.

Comment: I see. In this case, do we take all simplices in $sk_n(X)$ of degree $>n$ to be a point $\mathsf{pt}$?

Comment: $sk_mX$ is the minimal subssimplicial set of $X$ that contains all non-degenerate simplices in degree less than $m$. This can be constructed as the fibered product (intersection) of all simplicial sets that are subsimplicial sets of $X$ and that contain all non-degenerate simplices in degree less than $m$. In general $sk_m X$ will have many degenerate simplices in dimension higher than $m$.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, how do you take the pullback (fibered product) of all such subsimplicial sets? I'm only familiar with finitary intersections.

Comment: That isn't that good of a definition for the skeleton, it's not really important. Think of a simplex $\sigma$ in $X$ as being in the $m-$skeleton $sk_m X$ if for all maps $\phi, \Phi :X \rightarrow Y$ that agree on simplices in degree less than $m$ we have to have $\phi(\sigma) = \Phi(\sigma)$ for all simplicial sets $Y$. This means that $\sigma$ doesn't "add any new information" to $X$ that isn't already contained in the simplices of degree lower than $m$.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 But if you are curios we define infinite fiberproducts analogous to the way we define infinite products. Namely as the limit of an infinite diagram.

Comment: Ok, then is an infinite intersection just a limit of a functor from a discrete category to an over-category $\mathbf{sSet}/X$ (or maybe the full subcategory on all monos)?

Comment: Yes that is correct